# Sum values in Rows

Tags: r

here is my question.
I have a dataframe with 30 rows (corresponding to 30 questions in a questionnaire) with values from 1 to 5 as answers.
I would like to sum all values equal to 1 that appears in the 30 rows.
I tried with the command aggregate, but it doesn't work.

Comment: if your dataframe consists in a single column, `sum(df==1)`

Answer (score 0):

The question could use more clarity, code would help, but I will give you a theoretical of what I believe you are asking for

If you have a data frame `df` such that:

```
questions   ob1         ob2          ob 3
q1          5            3             1
q2          2            1             1
q3          4            1             5
```

and you want to add up all the values where something is equal to answer of 1 you have a number of options, but the most obvious is simply subset with a logical

or you could

```
sumob1<- sum(df$ob1[ , which(df$ob1==1)])
```

Watch for the leading comma in the [] it tells R to include all rows (on the left side of the comma) and just the values equal to the subset column on the right.

Which basically says I would like to make `sumob1` equal to the sum of the column ob1 for all  row cells in which column df$ob1 has a value of 1.

You can do that for each column.